# matching double quote in preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to match the pattern below and obtain the word target.

> INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN"  NAME="TITLE" VALUE="target ">

I try this but in vain.

```
preg_match('@(?:<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN"  NAME="TITLE" VALUE=")(.*)(?:">)@',$data,$matches);
```

I think the problem is because of double quote

I also try \" but still fail...

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work
'@(?:<INPUT TYPE=)@' is ok but even '@(?:<INPUT TYPE=")@' fails
So I think that the problem comes from double quote "

Comment: Found out what was wrong, double space on your pattern, details in my answer.

Comment: I bet whatever it is you're doing could be done better using [DOMDocument](http://php.net/domdocument) and [DOMXPath](http://php.net/domxpath) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It fails simply because you have a double space in your pattern in here (marked with `_` ):

```
INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN"__NAME="TITLE"
```

Remove one space there and it works, anyway here would be my attempt from scratch, case insensitive and either with `"` or `'` though I'm not sure if it's part of what you want that `name` has to be `title` in which case I'd have to edit it a bit.

```
<?php
    $data = '<input type="hidden" name="title" value="target">';
    preg_match('/<input[^>]+value=[\'"](\w*)[\'"][^>]*>/i',$data,$matches);
    echo $matches[1]; //=> target
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
preg_match('@<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="TITLE" VALUE="([^"]*)">@', $data, $matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close... You need to match usng (). It looks like you've got an extra )

```
preg_match('@<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN"  NAME="TITLE" VALUE="([^"]*)">@',$data,$matches);
```

[^"] - any character other than "

(  ) - matching part